# Correlation between " Time of the day" and an ordinal variable

Tags: correlation, spss, ordinal-data, real-time

My hypothesis is  The compliance score (Dependent/ ordinal variable) varies during a different time of the day. 
for example, I would expect high compliance between regular working hours 7 am - 5  pm -and lower scores between 5 PM and  7 am the next day.

I am not sure what test I should use.

Answer (score 0):

If the dependent measure has multiple categories that you want treated as ordinal (like low, medium, and high compliance) then look at the PLUM procedure in IBM SPSS Statistics in the Base module.